# Why can't I use quick actions/refactorings as a liveshare participant in VS 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-liveshare

Whenever I'm a participant in VS live share in visual studio community 2019 and I attempt to open the quick actions and refactorings, I get a message box saying "value cannot be null. Parameter name: key" with no indication as to what part of visual studio is trying to use a key or where I can fix this.
Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

I'm also finding that the programming experience is greatly diminished. It's almost like I'm writing c# in microsoft word.

The host of the session has enabled all settings for allowing access to participants.

My visual studio community 2019 version is 16.1.6

Comment: I would also like to know about this!